# A Specific Linear Homogeneous System of Differential Equations with Variable Coefficients

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Is there an analytical solution satisfying these 3 equations with non-constant z?

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-z\cdot\cos(\omega t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=z\cdot\sin(\omega t)$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=x\cdot\cos(\omega t) - y\cdot\sin(\omega t)$$

Pick a specific non-zero $\omega$ (e.g., 1 or $\pi$) if you must do so.

Comment: $x=\sin \omega t$, $y=\cos \omega t$, $z=-\omega $ seems to work.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I actually want non-constant z, so will edit my question.

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2$ stays constant for any solution, so you may do dimensional reduction

Comment: Can the downvoters at least give a reference for how to solve this problem?  Sorry, I simply can't see the trick to get the sqrt(1+w^2) sine wave unless I guess a single sine wave from the beginning and solve for parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is conserved, we can switch to the stereographic projection, i. e. substitute $x=\frac{2X}{X^2+Y^2+1}R$, $y=\frac{2Y}{X^2+Y^2+1}R$, $z=\frac{X^2+Y^2-1}{X^2+Y^2+1}R$, with constant $R$. This gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{dX}{dt}&=\frac12\cos(\omega t)(X^2-Y^2+1)-\sin(\omega t)XY,\\
\\
\frac{dY}{dt}&=\frac12\sin(\omega t)(X^2-Y^2-1)+\cos(\omega t)XY.
\end{align*}
Denoting $Z=X+iY$, we reduce to a single equation
$$
\frac{dZ}{dt}=\frac12\left(e^{i\omega t}Z^2+e^{-i\omega t}\right),
$$
solved as
$$
Z(t)=e^{-i\omega t}\left(\sqrt{1+\omega^2}\tan\left(\frac12\sqrt{1+\omega^2}t+C_0+iC_1\right)-i\omega\right)
$$
(with arbitrary real constants $C_0$, $C_1$).

The latter can be found by e. g. further switching to $F(t)=e^{i\omega t}Z(t)$ which satisfies
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}=\frac12\left(1+2i\omega F+F^2\right),
$$
giving
$$
t=C+\int\frac{2dF}{1+2i\omega F+F^2}=C_0+iC_1+\frac2{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{F+i\omega}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}\right)
$$

Returning to $(x,y,z)$ it is easy to see that this describes circular motion on a sphere around some axis like this

[image]

with the sphere itself at the same time spinning around the $z$ axis (because of the $e^{i\omega t}$ multiplier in $Z=e^{-i\omega t}F$), which means that there must be an easier method to solve the original system. In fact I suspect these are a case of [spinning top equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange,_Euler,_and_Kovalevskaya_tops)...

Comment: Thanks, it seems logical (though I was wrongly trying to use spherical coordinates from your hint instead of stereographic projection) except for the "solved as" step.  I checked that your Z(t) does indeed work but curious about how you found it.  If there's a method (i.e., not just a massive lookup) going on there, could you add some intermediate steps?

Comment: @bobuhito To be honest I just invoked Mathematica. Initially I tried dividing the equation by $Z$, giving $\frac d{dt}(\log Z)=\cos(\omega t-i\log(Z))$ but in the end you get nothing less complicated. If I'll manage to find something more transparent I will add it. Numerical experiments show that going back to $x,y,z$ you get circular trajectories on a sphere which is at the same time itself spinning around the $z$ axis

Comment: For that you switch to an autonomous system: multiplying the DE by $e^{i\omega t}$ you get for $F(t)=e^{i\omega t}Z(t)$ the equation $F'=\frac12\left(1+2i\omega F+F^2\right)$ or, if you prefer, for $G=\log(F)$, the equation $G'=\cosh(G)+i\omega$

Comment: Actually, you can then get a linear equation in a new variable H by defining F=-H'/H/2 (which has simple sine solutions, so the tangent and everything comes naturally now, thanks).

Comment: @bobuhito You mean $F=-2H'/H$?

Comment: And in fact, already for $F$, you can get a solution as$$t=C+\int\frac{2dF}{1+2i\omega F+F^2}=C_0+iC_1+\frac2{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{F+i\omega}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}}\right)$$

Comment: added the latter to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is more direct route. The previous solution suggests that the system might be simplified by imposing rotation around the $z$ axis with frequency $\omega$.

Indeed consider the substitution
\begin{align*}
x&=\tilde x\cos(\omega t)+\tilde y\sin(\omega t),\\
y&=\tilde y\cos(\omega t)-\tilde x\sin(\omega t),\\
z&=\tilde z,
\end{align*}
describing rotation around the $z$ axis superimposed on the motion according to $(\tilde x,\tilde y,\tilde z)$. Then for the latter we get
\begin{align*}
\tilde x'&=-\omega\tilde y-\tilde z,\\
\tilde y'&=\omega\tilde x,\\
\tilde z'&=\tilde x,
\end{align*}
which can be easily solved and gives
\begin{align*}
\tilde x&=-A\sqrt{1+\omega^2}\sin\left(\sqrt{1+\omega^2}t\right),\\
\tilde y&=A\omega\cos\left(\sqrt{1+\omega^2}t\right)+B,\\
\tilde z&=A\cos\left(\sqrt{1+\omega^2}t\right)-B\omega.
\end{align*}
This is rotation around the axis with direction $(0,\frac1{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}},-\frac\omega{\sqrt{1+\omega^2}})$ on a sphere of radius $\sqrt{(A^2+B^2)(1+\omega^2)}$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Maple finds rather complicated closed-form solutions where $z(t) = \cos(\sqrt{1+\omega^2} t)$ or $\sin(\sqrt{1+\omega^2}t)$.